# Media Library http to https

Tags: media-library, https

My website is currently displaying mixed content because the images from Media Library are in `http`.

I've used a few plugins to update the URL and search and replace all `http` references to `https`.

I've updated the `site url and site address via mysql`.

However, media library is still inconsistently using `http://`.

Where else do I have to update for Media Library to change to `https`?

Answer (score 0):

Force redirect HTTP to HTTPS using a plugin like [Really Simple SSL Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/), it's easy to use and it's free.

Comment: Thanks. The plugin certainly is a quick working solution but would like to know why Media Library is still not pointing to https and how to update it.

Comment: Did you try running SSL Insecure content fixer?  https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/  It will automatically perform some basic fixes and it analyzes the problem on your website - worked like a charm on one of our client websites.  They were having the same issues with the media library.